# `run` block in snakemake reset config value?

Tags: python, snakemake

For example, I have python script `snakemake.py`:

```
from snakemake import snakemake

cfg={'a':'aaaa', 'b':'bbbb', 'c': 'cccc'}
snakemake(
        'Snakefile',
        targets=['all'],
        printshellcmds=True,
        forceall=True,
        config=cfg,
        # configfile=config,
        keep_target_files=True,
        keep_logger=False)
```

`Snakefile` looks like this:

```
print(config)
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
rule a:
    output:
        'a.out'
    shell:
        "echo %s ; "
        "touch {output[0]}" % config['a']
rule b:
    output:
        'b.out'
    shell:
        "echo %s ; touch {output[0]}" % config['b']
rule c:
    output:
        'c.out'
    run:
        print(config['c'])
        import os
        os.system('touch ' + output[0])

rule all:
    input:
        'a.out', 'b.out', 'c.out'
```

When I run `python snakemake.py`, I met an error:

```
{'a': 'aaaa', 'c': 'cccc', 'b': 'bbbb'}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       a
        1       all
        1       b
        1       c
        4

rule c:
    output: c.out
    jobid: 1

{}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError in line 8 of /Users/zech/Desktop/snakemake/Snakefile:
'a'
  File "/Users/zech/Desktop/snakemake/Snakefile", line 8, in <module>
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

When I remove the `c.out` from `rule all`, then it runs perfectly fine. It looks like every `run` block in the rules reset `config` passed to `snakemake` function to empty? Isn't it a weird behavior? Is there any workaround?

I am using snakemake version 3.11.2 (installed from bioconda channel of anaconda) on latest OSX.

**NOTE:** It runs fine when I run snakemake command line `snakemake -p --keep-target-files all --config a="aaaa" b="bbb" c="cccc"`. So this looks like a problem for the API.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to not use the Snakemake command line client but the API?

Comment: @JohannesKöster, because I'd like to call snakemake inside my own packages, which is better to use API instead of run a command.

Comment: Could you file an issue at bitbucket? I think it is a bug.

Comment: @JohannesKöster, issue created

Answer (score 0):

What is your **current version of Snakemake**?

I use **snakemake/3.11.2** and I have no problem with your script.

But you have to know that the **params section** of each rules is the right way to invoke the `configuration parameters`.

In your script it should be like this :

```
rule a:
    params:
        name = config['a']
    output:
        'a.out'
    shell:
        "echo {params.name} ; "
        "touch {output}"
rule b:
    params:
        name = config['b']
    output:
        'b.out'
    shell:
        "echo {params.name} ;"
        "touch {output}"

rule c:
    params:
        name = config['c']
    output:
        'c.out'
    run:
        print(params.name)
        import os
        os.system('touch ' + output[0])
```

Comment: I was using version 3.11.0, but update to 3.11.2 does not solve it. How did you install snakemake? would it be possibly due to the conda build?

Comment: did you run the snakemake command line or API thru my python script? command line works fine but not the API.

Comment: Ohh ok ok ! I run snakemake in command line. So I tried your python script and the errors occurs like you said. Maybe launching snakemake with os.system() should resolve you problem.

Comment: that's less ideal. but looks like that's the workaround.